# How to parse a postgres POINT to x,y object

Tags: javascript, geometry

What is the best way to parse a postgres point type `"(12.2, -23.2)"` to something like an `{x,y}` object in javascript.

Googling the issue only gives "how to parse float" or "how to insert POINT to postgres"

Comment: Are you using node-postgres?

Comment: no, should i?...

Comment: Then how else do you get the data from the postgres db? How to parse it depends on what is available

Comment: from my api endpoint

Comment: I would suggest then to change your API endpoint so that it outputs points with a usable structured format instead of a string. If you can't do that, you'll have to work with string operations, e.g. `input.slice(1, -1).split(", ").map(x => parseFloat(x))`